# My first dig at jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a complete newbie as far as jQuery is concerned. I also don't know much of JavaScript except for some very basic stuff.

I'm following this tutorial here: http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

And nothing's working! :-)

I created a folder on my machine's hard drive here: C:\rnd\jQuery

Then, in that folder, I put the jquery.x.x.js file that I downloaded from the jQuery website and I created a test.html file and wrote the following code in it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      a.test { font-weight: bold; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").addClass("test");
        $("a").click(function(event) {
          alert("Thanks for visiting.");
          event.preventDefault();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

It just does the normal behavior of taking me to the jQuery website. I ran it on Chrome, IE and Firefox. I have JavaScript enabled in the browsers. It's all the same everywhere. It doesn't do anything that I expected it to do. It just takes me to the website.

Except on IE, it shows me that message box saying an error occurred in your script. When I click "Yes" to debug, it opens up the debugger but it doesn't highlight any line of code so I don't really know what's happening.

Then, when I had the following line to my code:

```
$("a").hide("slow");
```

And my complete code looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      a.test { font-weight: bold; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").addClass("test");
        $("a").click(function(event) {
          alert("Thanks for visiting.");
          event.preventDefault();
          $("a").hide("slow");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

At this, nothing different happens in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE, it breaks again into the debugger, this time with this line highlighted in yellow, and it reports that the identifier `jQuery` is not defined.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.textDropShadow = function(){
    $(this).html('<span class="jq-shadow">'+$(this).html()+'</span><span>'+$(this).html()+'</span>');
    return $(this);
  }
})(jQuery);
```

And that, I believe is some JavaScript code on the jQuery website.

I feel completely lost. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
I have my complete HTML and it is valid XHTML. It's too bad the browser displays that as an HTML response stream and I can't even get it to show up here as a script. Damn! How do you make HTML show up here?

Comment: Re: "Update": You click the "code" button in the editor.

Comment: I edited your question so HTML is correctly displayed

Comment: @David: I had done that already. That's why it pretty prints the script part, but hogs the HTML part.

Comment: I'd recommend to you that you install the firebug extension in firefox and get to know it. It's an invaluable tool for tracking down script & html problems.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can see one issue.  You have a `.` following the `$` in the document ready statement.

```
$.(document).ready(function()
 ^--- remove the .!
```

It should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

Comment: "You're the man, and I accepted your answer" would sound better. `;-)`

Comment: I did want to, but I had to wait a couple of minutes before SO would let me accept any answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

First off make sure you have the jQuery library referenced before writing any jQuery code (or loading any plugins)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{path to jquery.x.x.js}" ></script>
```

Also, it should be $(document).ready(function() { });

not $.(document)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the problem was an extra dot in the $.document part however here is a tip for you when learning jquery.

You may find yourself in the situation that you have another javascript library running on the page and it's using the $ symbol too. A good way to keep your jquery separate from the other library but still share the $ symbol is to alias $ inside your jquery init statement.. like so.

// the dollar symbol doesn't exist outside of this as we started it with jQuery so i personally like this approach.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#...');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Great tip. I also learnt from the API a short while ago that I could use the .noConflict() function to tell the JavaScript interpreter that I will use the name jQuery instead of the $ sign as it might have been overloaded by some native JavaScript code. Thanks for letting me know this.

Comment: Yes basically the same thing! You're on the right track, noConflict() might be preferred because it's self-documenting meaning that the function name implies what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

You need to show more of your page for us to know what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, I did. I'd formatted my script as code as well but it doesn't show up. I tried enclosing everything in a <pre> tag as well but it didn't show up even then. Sad.

Comment: @Water Cooler v2: You just have to indent your code by four spaces and it will be formatted as such. No special HTML tags needed.

Comment: @Andy E: How did you know I'd done that? Wow! I know I'm sounding dumb but I guess that's how we all do when we're newbies.

Comment: @Andy E: Oh, I see. It's right up there, it shows the script inclusion. Sorry. :-)

Comment: @Water: Users with 2k rep here can edit your post and see the source.  David Dorward posted the same answer as this one, then shortly afterwards deleted it with a comment saying *"Oh, you have..."*.